# Python If statement and While loop Bug with recursion

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

Hello I defined this small function with recursion:

```
def z_positions(frame,init_grid,f_count,_limit_):
    if f_count<_limit_:
        for i in range(np.shape(init_grid)[0]):
            for j in range(np.shape(init_grid)[0]):
                if init_grid[i,j]==1:
                    init_grid[i,j]=Z[f_count][i,j]
                else:
                    pass
        f_count+=1
        print(f_count<_limit_)
        new_grid=frame[f_count]
        z_positions(frame,new_grid,f_count,_limit_)
    else:
        print('end')
        return(frame)
```

So as you can see, the function calls itself only if the `f_count` is `<` than the `_limit_`, the `frame` parameter is only an `np.array` with more `np.array` inside with `1` and `0` values, and the parameter `init_grid` is only the first `np.array` of `frame` or better said `frame[0]`.

What the function is doing is only replacing the values equal to `1` with some value from an identical `np.array` called `Z` that contains positions along the `Z` axis; however, even though `f_count` reaches the level of the `_limit_` keeps executing the `True` portion of the `if` statement, which later returns me error as `f_count` surpassed the permited indexes as you can see here:

```
<ipython-input-49-0ac0d93e899c> in z_positions(frame, init_grid, f_count, _limit_)
 10         print(f_count<_limit_)
 11         new_grid=frame[f_count]
---> 12         z_positions(frame,new_grid,f_count,_limit_)
 13     else:
 14         print('end')

<ipython-input-49-0ac0d93e899c> in z_positions(frame, init_grid, f_count, _limit_)
  9         f_count+=1
 10         print(f_count<_limit_)
---> 11         new_grid=frame[f_count]
 12         z_positions(frame,new_grid,f_count,_limit_)
 13     else:

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I added the `print(f_count<_limit_)` to know what is happening and I can see that what I just said above is `True` because it prints `False` and it suppodsely should not do it as the `print` instruction should be excecuted only if the statement is `True` (same situation if I use `while f_count<_limit_:`). Could you please help me by pointing out what I am missing? Thanks! (Here a pic of the printting I just mentioned)

[image: printing output]

Comment: Not related to the error: You need to return the recursive call: `return z_positions(frame, new_grid, f_count, _limit_)`

Comment: It still shows same error.

Comment: I said my change wouldn't fix the error, it's a separate problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Put `f_count+=1` after `new_grid=frame[f_count]`. You are now increasing f_count first and than indexing new_grid with it.

Comment: Do you still have the error? Maybe the `_limit_` variable is not set correct?

Comment: Hello, thank you for commenting. Finally I removed it and defined a new function like this:

    `def z_positions(frame,count):
        if count<stop:
            for i in range(np.shape(frame[count])[0]):
                for j in range(np.shape(frame[count])[0]):
                    if frame[count][i,j]==1:
                        frame[count][i,j]=Z[count][i,j]else:
                        pass
            z_positions(frame,count+1)
        else:
            pass
    z_positions(frames_init_mass_grid,0)
    frames_init_mass_grid`